# $content fields missing in node.tpl.php for teaser (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In `node.tpl.php` I've got `<?php print_r(array_keys($content)) ?>`. When viewing the node as a full page, it prints this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => links
    [1] => body
    [2] => field_address
    [3] => field_rating
    [4] => field_picture
)
```

And when viewing the node as a teaser on the front page it prints this:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => links 
    [1] => body 
)
```

How can I get `field_rating` and `field_picture` to be available when I'm theming the teaser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn fields on and off for the teaser in the following admin page:

Administration > Structure > Content Types > Manage Display > Teaser (Tab)